# Load multiple images to be placed from one document? - InDesign CC

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, file-placing

I am wondering if there is a function in InDesign if you have multiple pages in one document to place into the file it can have them loaded? Just like when you multi-select different files to place and it has them loaded to place on the cursor. At the moment I am just clicking to the page in the import options and placing them in one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multi-place cursor happens because you **select** *multiple files* to be placed.

It doesn't happen if you are placing the same file repeatedly. 1 file = 1 place, doesn't matter if the file has multiple pages.

---

If you are placing a **multi-page PDF**, there's a script.. Choose `Window > Utilities > Scripts` to open the **Scripts Panel**.

In the Scripts Panel under `Application > Samples` there is a script for **PlaceMultiPagePDF** -- On a Mac, it's actually located in both the Applescript samples and the Javascript samples.